# How do I access another user's registry hive using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, registry

How can I use Powershell to load and alter another user's registry hive, without having to shell out to another Powershell process run as the target user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to load their registry.

```
reg load HKU\<username> C:\Users\<username>\ntuser.dat
```

You can find more detailed information on this here though:
https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/manipulating-registry-user-hive

Comment: Once you are done manipulating the HKEY_USERS registry hive, don’t forget to unload it: `$null = REG UNLOAD HKEY_Users\<username>`

Comment: While it is given considering the question asks about accessing another users registry, I wanna point out that this does not work for the logged in user as that file will be in use. I encountered that error when running a script as authority system and wanted to access current user registry using this method. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer helped me solve my issue, I've since learned how to do this with pure PowerShell using the [`Registry` provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_registry_provider?view=powershell-7.2):

```
# Mount the HKEY_USERS hive
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS

# Change location to the user's registry (organized by SID)
cd HKU:/$userSid
```

This works by mounting the `HKEY_USERS` hive as a new `PSDrive` named `HKU`, which other user hives are accessible under a sub-key named after the target user's SID. You can determine the SID in one of two ways (assuming you don't already know the SID ahead of time):

- Local account:

  ```
  $userSid = ( Get-LocalUser NAME ).SID.Value
  ```
- Domain Account<sup>[1]</sup>:

  ```
  $userSid = ( Get-ADUser NAME ).SID.Value
  ```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> `Get-ADUser` is available with the [RSAT Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/remote-server-administration-tools) AD cmdlets, which must be installed as a prerequisite for this command to work.

Comment: This works only if the hive is already loaded, i.e. if the user is already logged on, otherwise you still need `reg load`.