# Cannot find registry path running a powershell script as a custom action

Tags: powershell, registry, custom-action, vs-installer-project

I have a PowerShell script where I am reading and editing registry.

I tried running it manually, calling it from command line, converting it to an .exe with `ps2exe`, and for all of those scenarios it works as intended. However, when I package it with my installer (using MS Visual Studio Installer Projects) and try running it as `Custom Actions/Commit/script.exe`, it suddenly cannot find the registry keys.

Here's a snippet of my script.

```
## initializing new variables
$req_path = Get-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options" |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property
echo $req_path
```

> ```
> ERROR: Get-Item : Cannot find path
> 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options' because it doesnot exist.
> ```

I have also tried this variation to no avail:

```
$req_path = Get-Item -Path Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property
```

Since this is part of the installer, it runs as admin, so privileges are not the culprit.

So, How can I access the registry keys when running a PowerShell script as a custom action?

Some additional info.:

- `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` returns `True`
- `WhoAmI` returns `nt authority\system`

Comment: I'm not positive but it sounds like the custom action might be somehow launching a 32 bit version of powershell so when it's trying to find the values it can't since it'll be in the 64 bit registry hive not 32 bit. [Maybe check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630382/how-to-access-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-powershell-instance) and see if it relates to what you are doing.  I have run into something similar before with package deployment/creation and it ended up being that it was launching a 32 bit version of PowerShell and couldn't find the keys that I knew exsisted.

Comment: Looks like it runs under a different user. What returns `WhoAmI`?

Comment: @kconsiglio I checked the ```[Environment]::Is64BitProcess``` and it returned True. But what you're saying is my guess too. I am trying to set the reg path like this to see if that resolves the issue: ```[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::CurrentUser, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView]::Registry64)```

Comment: @M-- odd, if it's returning true than the script is running in 64 bit and should be able to find the values I would think. Could it be running as a different user under the installer like iRon suggested?

Comment: @iRon it runs under `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`

Comment: @kconsiglio most probably that's the issue. I am trying to set/get something in/from HKCU but I don't think I can do that for `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

Comment: You would need to load (and unload) the user's registry hive, see e.g. [How do I access another user's registry hive using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057552/1701026)

Comment: @iRon that doesn't work; I am getting an error: ```ERROR: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.```

Comment: @iRon please see my solution below; I appreciate if you could provide any feedback on what can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Considering that I am not an expert in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), there is a great chance that there is a better way or at least my implementation is not the most efficient one, but I found a way.</sup>

```
## HKCU is not accessible when running the script from nt\ authority system
## Hence, accessing the HKU/SID for the current user
## finding current user's SID
## list of profiles
$profileIP = 
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*") | 
Select-Object ProfileImagePath
$profileIP = $profileIP.ProfileImagePath

## list of SIDs
$SIDs = 
(Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\") | 
Select-Object Name 
$SIDs = (Split-Path $SIDs -Leaf).Trim("{}")

## finding the SID for the current user
$sid_index = 0

foreach ($entry in $profileIP) {
    if ($entry.ToString().ToUpper().Contains($env:USERNAME.ToUpper())){break}
    $sid_index += 1
}

$CU_SID = $SIDs[$sid_index]

## initiating HKU for this instance of powershell
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS

## Get items under SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options
$req_ref = -join @("HKU:\",$CU_SID,"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options")
$req_path = Get-Item -Path $req_ref |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property
```

Comment: "*Considering that I am not an expert in powershell*", this looks pretty good. The idea of using a `New-PSDrive` is actually better than the answer I referred you to.  There are a few things that I would do different but I don't have much time today to go in detail.  A few ideas, to receive the users SID: `(Get-LocalUser $Env:USERNAME).SID.Value`. and at the end you might use `Set-Location` to refer to your HKU path. Anyways, I recommend to post your code at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I started with `Get-LocalUser` but for some unknown reason it only returns these accounts and *"Administrator, DefaultAccount, Guest, WDAGUtilityAccount"* so when I try to get it for the logged in user with `$Env:UserName`, it gives me an error: `Get-LocalUser : User MyUserName was not found`. Posting to code review was a great suggestion. It's been a while since I posted anything there. Thank you.